# Error creating bean with name 'controllerx':

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

**my controller:**

```
package com.market;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;




@Controller 
public class Controllerx {

    @Autowired
    private View frame;


/*
    private void init() {
        this.frame.addWindowListener(this);
        registerAction(frame.getbEnter(), new AbstractAction() {
            private List<Funcionarios> list; 

            @Override
            public void action() {
                if (!frame.getjLogin().getText().trim().isEmpty() || !frame.getjPassword().getText().trim().isEmpty()) {

                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, null, "Campo vázio", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void posAction() {
                cleanUp();
            }
        });
    }
    */
    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

**my main:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Market1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Market1Application.class).headless(false).run(args);
        Controllerx appLogin = context.getBean(Controllerx.class);
    }

}
```

**my view:**

```
package com.market;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class View extends JFrame{

    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 350;
    static final int FRAME_X_ORIGIN = 150;
    static final int FRAME_Y_ORIGIN = 150;
    static final int BUTTON_WIDTH = 90;
    static final int BUTTON_HEIGHT = 30;
    private JTextField jLogin;
    private JTextField jPassword;
    private JButton bEnter;
    private JButton bRegister;
    private JPanel loginForm;
    private JLabel loginText;
    private JLabel passwordText;

    public View() {
        setTitle("Login System");
        setSize         (FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        setLocation     (FRAME_X_ORIGIN, FRAME_Y_ORIGIN);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setResizable(false);
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {
        loginForm = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
        //buttons
        bRegister = new JButton("Registrar");
        bRegister.setBounds(195, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        bEnter = new JButton("Registrar");
        bEnter.setBounds(195, 285, BUTTON_WIDTH, BUTTON_HEIGHT);
        //bEnter.setMnemonic(NativeKeyEvent.VC_ENTER);
        //labels
        loginText = new JLabel();
        loginText.setText("Username:");
        passwordText = new JLabel();
        passwordText.setText("Password:");
        //
        loginForm.add(loginText);
        loginForm.add(jLogin);
        loginForm.add(passwordText);
        loginForm.add(jPassword);
        loginForm.add(bEnter);
        loginForm.add(bRegister);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void resetForm() {
        jLogin.setText("");
        jPassword.setText("");
    }
    public JTextField getjLogin() {
        return jLogin;
    }
    public void setjLogin(JTextField jLogin) {
        this.jLogin = jLogin;
    }
    public JTextField getjPassword() {
        return jPassword;
    }
    public void setjPassword(JTextField jPassword) {
        this.jPassword = jPassword;
    }
    public JButton getbEnter() {
        return bEnter;
    }
    public void setbEnter(JButton bEnter) {
        this.bEnter = bEnter;
    }

}
```

i have these errors compiling i don't know where i went wrong i have only these 3 classes

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. ERROR
>   o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'controllerx': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'frame'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'view' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\Gabriel\eclipse-workspace\gabrielestudo\market-1\target\classes\com\market\View.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.market.View]: Constructor threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
>     at com.market.Market1Application.main(Market1Application.java:16)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'view' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\Gabriel\eclipse-workspace\gabrielestudo\market-1\target\classes\com\market\View.class]:
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.market.View]: Constructor threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
>     ... 22 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.market.View]: Constructor threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295)
>     ... 33 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
>   java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.market.View.initComponents(View.java:56)  at
>   com.market.View.(View.java:39)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
>     ... 35 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JTextField` variable with name `jLogin` is null (it's field and you didn't initialize it) and that's why you have NPE when doing

```
loginForm.add(jLogin);
```

take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) of the `JPanel` class - there is an information in `add` method section

> ```
> public Component add(Component comp)
> ```
>
> Throws: NullPointerException - if comp is null

seems that you will have the same issue at least on line **58** during adding `jPassword`

---

BTW you should read logs carefully because everything is there

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>
> at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
>
> at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
>
> at com.market.View.initComponents(**View.java:56**)
>
> at com.market.View.(**View.java:39**) at

Comment: omg i had forgotten to declare
thank you very much bro
could you give me a hand? I have a bean error when I try to add more classes

Comment: if you can help me